# Python - Can't Import ParametricModel from astropy.modeling

Tags: python, astropy

I am trying to import ParametricModel as follows:

```
from astropy.modeling import ParametricModel
```

But it shows following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: cannot import name ParametricModel

Why can't I import ParametricModel?

Comment: I am not familiar with this package and their documentation is confusing. At one point, this model was located in `astropy.modeling.core.ParametricModel`. Does making that change work? (`from astropy.modeling.core import ParametricModel`)

Answer (score 0):

That class was renamed in Astropy v0.4.  See the API changes in the [changelog](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/changelog.html#id30) for details (under the `astropy.modeling` section).  Make sure any documentation you're looking at matches your astropy version (via `astropy.__version__`).